# records don't appear in RS when updating records using a userform commandbutton

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform

I'm trying to append/update a certain record in the access db using a userform in Excel. I had the table imported from access DB to a list box, then when rows are double clicked, it copies the entries to text boxes which does it without fail. But when I change the values in the boxes, supposedly, it should update/append the record in the DB when the append button is clicked. However, it doesn't.

```
Private Sub cmdAppend_Click()
    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim varr As String

    'add error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

    If Me.Arec36.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter Child Case.", _
        vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Insufficent data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

    varr = Me.Arec36


    'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
    '—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
    'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "\\10.4.1.62\RiskTeam\Dispute Core Team Original\Chimp Change\Analysis\Database\ChimpDB.accdb"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the data from table.
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tbl_raw " & _
    "WHERE Child_Ref = " & varr, ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdText

    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        'Close the recordet and the connection.
        rs.Close
        cnn.Close

        'clear memory
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cnn = Nothing

        'Enable the screen.
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"

        Exit Sub
    End If

    With rs
        For i = 22 To 35
            rs(Cells(1, i).Value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & i).Value
            Next i
        rs.Update
    End With

    'clear the userform values
    For X = 22 To 35
        Me.Controls("Arec" & X).Value = ""
        Me.Arec36.Value = ""
        Me.Arec37.Value = ""
    Next

    'Close the recordset and the connection.
    rs.Close
    cnn.Close

    'clear memory
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

    'refresh the listbox
    ImportUserForm

    'Enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Me.lstDataAccess.RowSource = "DataAccess"

    'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.
    MsgBox "Congratulation the data has been appended", vbInformation, "Append successful"

    'error handler
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    'clear memory
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Append_Data"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through to confirm that your recordset is actually getting data? Do any of your message box prompts fire? Note that you're only going to update 1 record with the RS even if it does return data.

Comment: Hey Mike, the list box displays the entire record, which I can choose from. When I choose it, it puts the details in the record in the textboxes provided for them. Using the same textboxes, I should be able to append/edit the data. That's where I am at right now.

Comment: Per your comment to the answer below, have you been receiving the error "no records in recordset" all along? Have you ensured that `varr` is being populated correctly by stepping through the code and checking the value either in the immediate window or the watches window?

Comment: Using the watch window, it says `out of context` under value while Empty under Type.

Comment: Its suggested to use `Me.Arec36.Value` as opposed to `Me.Arec36` as you're specifically defining what to put into the variable as opposed to relying on default properties.  Not sure but my guess is the variable isn't transferring correctly.  Try stepping through the code to the `varr = Me.Arec36` and in the immediate window use `? Me.Arec36` / `? Me.Arec36.Value` and see if it returns a value.

Comment: added a watch for the `varr` when it changes. Stopped at the `cnn.open` line. It displays the actual value that should be equal to the table field entry.

Comment: Ah, is varr value a string or a number?  If its a string, your sql is going to be formatted and interpreted as `"SELECT * FROM tbl_raw WHERE Child_Ref = String"`.  Where if its a text value it should be `"SELECT * FROM tbl_Raw WHERE Child_Ref = 'STRING'"`

Comment: I did this, `"SELECT * FROM tbl_raw WHERE Child_Ref = varr",` and I got `No value given for one or more required parameters`

Comment: Change it to `"SELECT * FROM tbl_raw WHERE Child_Ref = '" & varr & "'"`

Comment: I got a type mismatch error

Comment: What is an example value for `varr` and what is the table column type for `Child_ref` in `tbl_Raw`?

Comment: Example value is `427926-100219-1-1` and the column type is `Short Text`

Comment: Alright, try updating to this - "SELECT * FROM tbl_raw WHERE Child_Ref = """ & varr & """" - The single quotes may be causing an issue. Not sure how you weren't getting an error before when supplying a string value without any quotes in the first place though.

Comment: I tried to determine where the error actually stops and I saw it here.`rs(Cells(1, i).Value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & i).Value` our SQL statement seems to be working.

Comment: Are the row 1 values you are trying to reference the same as the field names inside the database? Also, might be worth changing `Cells` to `Sheets("mySheetName").Cells(1,i).Value`. Also, reading your code, these "headers" would be starting at "V1" and continuing from there. Does that sound right?

Comment: My guess is, whatever value in your `.Cells(1,i) ` does not reference a string value or the value contained within does not match the headers of the database table.  Testing your code works fine on my end. Might be worth breaking out your loop and instead of looping through 12 columns, just use RS!FieldNameHere = Me.ArecFieldNumber.Value followed by RS.Update to ensure that its updating.

Comment: @mike the `RS!Fieldnamehere` worked!. The last error that I am getting is that when I put a date in the `Me.ArecFieldNumber.Value` works, however, if I try to put `blank` in the `Me.ArecFieldNumber.Value`, it says `type mismatch`. How do we go about this last item? You've been a great help.

Comment: Try blocking that one in an if statement. You can do something different, but for testing its probably easier to do `If isdate(Me.ArecDateField) Then RS!DateField = Me.ArecDateField Else RS!DateField = Null End If`. Not sure if that will work, can't test it at the moment.

Comment: I like the idea.. I'll test it tomorrow once I come in. Just got out of the office.

Comment: @mike the `if statement` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the **Options:=adCmdText** might be sufficient. The procedure isn't implemented as a Command.

To add rows you need to have **.AddNew** before your update.

Comment: I'm still getting the same message/error that I put in **There are no records in the recordset!**

Comment: It could be **varr = Me.Arec36** instead of **varr = Me.Arec36.value**. I can't recall if that is necessary for userform controls.

Answer (score 0):

RS is an index of the Access DB connection.  DB's do not have cells.  If you wanted to Write to RS, just reference the index FIELD as in RS(FIELDS(1, i).Value).  But, your query is also a select statement.  You cannot update a record set with a select statement, unless you are inserting into another table.  In order to update the record, you need to issue an UPDATE on the INDEX!  I hope this helps out.

Comment: Blank is not a valid date. Your Database is expecting a date.  It may be required on the table, or will not accept a "", because it is a value.  Try inserting NULL instead of blank or "".